# LINQ Group by and count concatenated output

Tags: c#, linq

With this query:

```
foreach(var y in items)
{
        <div>@y.fieldA => @y.FieldB</div>
}
```

I get this output:

```
3 => 2
3 => 1
2 => 2
3 => 2
```

I know in LINQ we can easily count and group by with this:

```
foreach(var y in items.GroupBy(g => g.Field)
                      .Select(group => new {Field = group.Key, count = group.Count()}))
{
    <div>@y.Field : @y.count</div>
}
```

But how can I adapt this to the concatenated output so that I can get this result:

```
3 => 2 : 2
3 => 1 : 1
2 => 2 : 1
```

Comment: What is `.Field` in the last code snippet?

Comment: Please show us what is `items`. I mean it's clear that it is an `IEnumerable<T>` so please show definition of `T`

Comment: .Field is the column to be grouped and counted.
var items = AsDynamic(App.Data["data"])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Select` to project the desired string instead of projecting an anonymous object:

```
foreach(var item in items.GroupBy(g => $"{g.FieldA} => {g.FieldB}")
                         .Select(g => $"{g.Key} : {g.Count()}"))
{
    <div>@item</div>
}
```

For a pre C# 6.0 version:

```
foreach(var item in items.GroupBy(g => g.FieldA + " => " + g.FieldB)
                         .Select(g => g.Key + " : " + g.Count()))
{
    <div>@item</div>
}
```

Comment: Error CS1056: Unexpected character '$'